# How can a person make his/her immune system stronger and prevent flu?

Tags: nutrition, immune-system, meal

If someone is getting flu frequently, how can he/she make his/her immune system become stronger? And what should he/she eat for daily meals?

Answer (score 1):

I use Vitamin D3 to prevent that sort of illness in my home.  It has been used by many doctors & is more & more being promoted for this, as flu season is strongly linked to shortened days & lower D3 levels in research.  I do believe it's working as I have seen far fewer illnesses in general and have not gotten the flu now in many years since starting this.

Here is a link to some information about D3 and it's use in this regard. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4463890/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, please don't deliberately eat moldy bread.
It contains a spore/fungus. Ingesting that would be detrimental to the body since spores are exponentially harder to kill than germs or bacteria. 
The only thing you're getting from moldy bread is food poisoning and pain.

Germs/Bacteria that you find on the playground, when you bite your nails or eat without washing your hands, are the ones that boost your immunity because those kind of germs are easy to kill. The body's immune response is enough to form an antibody against that germ.

If you want to prevent the flu or get rid of it quickly, antibiotics would help. Advil Cold and Sinus works best for my patients. If that's not your path, then you can go with apple cider vinegar TID for 1 week.

Comment: if you want to comment on someone else's answer, when you have 50 rep you can do so. Your answer should stand on its own not as a rebuttal to someone else's. I am going to edit your answer to be independent.

Comment: Also, antibiotics DO NOT WORK for viruses such as the flu. A quick reading of your answer might lead someone to believe "Advil Cold and Sinus" was an example of an antibiotic, which it is not. And you have no sources for your claim that eating dirt and failing to wash your hands will somehow improve the immune system. This answer still needs a lot of work.

Comment: Antibiotics will not help prevent the flu. -1

Answer (score -2):

To make your immune system stronger simply.....Live in Haiti.

I did for 8 years now I never get sick.

Ok here's a my theory that I learned from 10th grade biology last year. Ok here's how to stronger your immune system.

**First**

Eat some infected food, like, moldy bread. 
Just eat anything that has bacteria in it! 
Don't eat to much obviously, the bacteria can overcome your body which can be fatal. 
Just eat enough to get you a bit sick.

**Second**

Now once you start feeling a bit sick, guess what, your body is producing antibodies to fight off the bacteria that is invading. When you body produces a certain type of antibodies it will "store" the DNA of that antibody and will produce it again if that same bacteria or like it invades again. (So if you want to protect against the flu..simply kiss your wife who already has the flu). 
You body will produce antibodies that fight the flu bacteria or virus.  You will want to take some antibiotics. Antibiotics just stimulate the immune system to create **more** antibodies. This is a faster way to become immune to a certain bacteria(sickness)

If you didn't take antibiotics your bodies antibodies will likely get dominated by the bacteria that you got from your wife! Then you will have to go to the doctor and tell them about what you read from me on Stack. Then he will likely sue, you probably will too. Anyway the doctor will then give you some antibiotics and tell you to get some rest.

This theory is mine!

Don't sue me I'm just a 16 year old with no life.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].